# Not able to transpile jsx to js using babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am learning react and here is my simple project sturcture:

```
my_project
 --node_modules
 --index.js
 --index.html
 --package.json
 --.babelrc
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "my_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "frontend using react js",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "babel src -d dist"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel --presets es2015 -d dist"
  },
  "author": "kishan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx"],
    "ignore": [
      "foo.js",
      "bar/**/*.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');

config = {
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/build",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

I am getting following error in console in browser for index.js line 1:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Please help me what is wrong with this code?

Comment: can you add the webpack.config.js file

Comment: Sure updated the question with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to define the `babel-loader` in `webpack` file, put this part:

```
module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```

Use this webpack file:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {
   context: __dirname,
   devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
   entry: "./index.js",
   output: {
      path: __dirname + "/build",
      filename: "bundle.js"
   },
   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   plugins: debug ? [] : [
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
   ],   
}

module.exports = config;
```

**Update:**

From [Webpack Doc](https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/):

> When using watch mode, webpack installs file watchers to all files,
>   which were used in the compilation process. If any change is detected,
>   it’ll run the compilation again. When caching is enabled, webpack
>   keeps each module in memory and will reuse it if it isn’t changed.

Comment: Ok thank you. I want to ask that index.html is pointing to bundle.js so every time i make changes in my dev code i have to build using webpack and then check ? Isn't that cumbersome ?

Comment: if any change happen to code webpack automatically do the changes in bundle.js file, you don't need to run the webpack again and again :) that is called webpack watch mode check this: https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/

Answer (score 1):

Add `babel-loader` in webpack to transpile jsx or js

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');

config = {
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/build",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

Starting the webpack in watch mode and will not require you to build again to do that add the followign in your `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress --color --config  webpack.config.js --watch",
}
```

You may also use `webpack-dev-server` in hot-loading mode

Comment: If you want webpack to autobuild you can start it in watch mode